# Importing CSV using pgfutter to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, import-csv

I am trying to import a csv file that has 17000 rows and columns and having some issues with it. I am able to import any other csv file into postgresql except this file. I tried reducing the file to 10 rows and 17000 columns but the issue is still there which means the size of the file is not an issue. The column names are just numbers from 0 to 17000. I have a feeling its the number of columns that can be the issue.

Downloaded from [here](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter/releases/download/v1.2/pgfutter_darwin_amd64).

Commands used in mac terminal:

```
$chmod +x pgfutter_darwin_amd64.dms

$./pgfutter_darwin_amd64 --host "127.0.0.1" --port "5432" --db "movie_lens" --schema "public" --table "movies2" --user "postgres" --pw "XXXXX" csv movies_cos_sim.csv
```

Once the commands are entered the output is just a list of all the column names but nothing shows up in postgresql.

Any ideas what I should do? Any other methods that can do this?

Comment: hello! welcome to stack overflow :) why did you use the python and python-3.x tags? this seems to be totally unrelated to python

Comment: fixed it, thanks! eventually I will work with postgresql and python so thought maybe someone will suggest another method without needing pgfutter

Comment: I see! Just a tip for your next question - we had no way of knowing that, and "what's the best way to use postgresql with python" is a very different question from "how do I use pgfutter to import a csv into postgresql" so they probably belong in different questions :)

Comment: @Mido2009 Did you find a solution???

Comment: @Arnab I went through another route. My huge matrix was a similarity score between all the movies I had. Instead of computing it all and storing it, I compute it every time a user picks a movie. Not sure if this helps your case though.

Comment: @Mido2009 I did manage to get it working, apparently I was making a silly error somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately pg_futter doesn't really show errors in many cases. For instance, if the username of the db is wrong, it will just exit with no output of the error. Exit code 0, too. You can only spot that there's an error because it finishes so quickly. And of course, because there's no data in the db :)

With pg_futter, itt's a matter of trial and error.

Some things that I encountered:

- the DB user/pass/dbname/host was wrong
- some files worked only after converting their line endings to Windows with unix2dos (even though I'm running everything on Linux)